# Breadth-first search(BFS) Implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, breadth-first-search

I have implemented a BFS. Does this look like a proper implementation of BFS in Python 3? And if you think something needs to be improved, say it.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.adjacencyList = []
        self.visited = False
        self.predecessor = None

class BreadthFirstSearch(object):

    def bfs(self, startNode):

        queue = []
        queue.append(startNode)
        startNode.visited = True

        # BFS -> queue      
        while queue:

            actualNode = queue.pop(0)
            print(actualNode.name)

            for n in actualNode.adjacencyList:
                if not n.visited:
                    n.visited = True
                    queue.append(n)

node1 = Node("A")
node2 = Node("B")
node3 = Node("C")
node4 = Node("D")
node5 = Node("E")

node1.adjacencyList.append(node2)
node1.adjacencyList.append(node3)
node2.adjacencyList.append(node4)
node4.adjacencyList.append(node5)

bfs = BreadthFirstSearch()
bfs.bfs(node1)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. When doing a search, shouldn't you be searching for something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) issues:

- In Python3, class definitions have been overhauled a bit, and one can simply do `class Node:` instead of `class Node(object):`.
- The spacing is a bit all over the place: there should be two blank lines between class definitions, and I find the spacing within `def bfs(self, start_node)` difficult.
- The naming convention is to be snake_cased.

To address this type of issues, have a look at [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html#quickstart) or [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

`Node.visited` is problematic.
First, if the node is in several trees, you may not visit it if it's already been  visited in another tree, or even in the same tree when doing a second search.

The fact that you have visited a node is part of the algorithm, and not so much a property of a `Node`.

With a few tweaks you can rely on `queue` only, or have a second list of visited:

```py
visited = []
for node in current_node.adjacency_list:
   if not node in visited:
        visited.append(node)
```

The comment `#BFS -> queue` is not very telling.

Lastly, this is iterating through the tree, and not doing actual search. Where's the exit condition? What's returned? What should I get when searching for `node4` from `node1`? `node4` from `node3`? `node3` from `node2`?

It's not quite done...

Answer (score 2):

#### collections.deque()

The documentation for `collections.deque()` says it is more efficient than a list when appending/popping elements. (Popping the 0th element from a list, may cause the rest of the list to be copied forward one space.)  So use a deque instead of a list for the queue.

#### set()

Use a `set()` instead of a `list()` for the adjacent nodes.  Also use a set for the visited nodes.  This lets you do set difference to determine what nodes to add to the queue.

```
from collections import deque

def bfs(self, startNode):

    visited_set = set(startNode)
    queue = deque(visited_set)

    while queue:

        actual_node = queue.popleft()
        print(actual_node.name)

        unvisited_nodes = actual_node.adjacency_set - visited_set
        for node in unvisited_nodes:

            # here is where you test to see if `node` is the search target
            # and take some action if it is.

        # otherwise append all the unvisited nodes to the queue and continue searching
        queue.extend(unvisited)
        visited_set |= unvisited
```